# Build .aar file

Tags: maven

I am trying to build axis2.aar file which contains an xml file from path ${basedir}\src\main\resources\conf\axis2.aar\axis2.xml but when we add the plugin for it into pom.xml it builds the .aar file with all the other contents like .java , .class , .properties etc. I only want .xml in it. Below is the plugin we are adding

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-aar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
            <execution>
                    <id>axis2</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <aarName>axis2</aarName>
                        <directory>${basedir}\src\main\resources\conf\axis2.aar\</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: <directory> parameter is not valid. you may include this in fileSets. please refer to https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-aar-plugin.html

Comment: Added it inside fileSets tag as well.Still not working.

Comment: Just below <configuration>  we need to add a line <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/aar</classesDirectory>